# 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable, for loop with list

Tags: python, pandas

I wish to do the following iteratively for a list of files of the form 'name.csv':

1. Read the file in with pandas,
2. Apply a function "datacropper" to the file
3. Generate a .csv of the updated file using the pandas .to_csv command, with name of the form 'cut-name.csv'.

These steps all work separately outside of a for loop. However, when I iterate over the files, I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Below is my attempt. How can I bypass this error?

```py
nameslist = ['pi89_1','pi89_ph7_1','pi89_ph7p48','pi89_ph6p49','pi89_ph7_2']

for i in range(len(nameslist)): 
    nameslist[i] = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file/" + str(nameslist[i]) + ".csv", index_col = 0)
    nameslist[i] = datacropper(str(nameslist[i]), 400, 800)
    nameslist[i].to_csv("/path/to/file/" + 'cut-' + str(nameslist[i]) + ".csv")
```

Comment: In the first line of your loop, you overwrite `nameslist[i]` with a dataframe.  In the third line of your loop, you are expecting `nameslist[i]` to be a file name.  The file name is long gone, replaced with a dataframe.  Perhaps you should just use a scratch variable name for the DataFrame, like the traditional `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something more like this.  Note that it is not necessary to use `str()` on your file names.  They are already strings.

```
nameslist = ['pi89_1','pi89_ph7_1','pi89_ph7p48','pi89_ph6p49','pi89_ph7_2']

for name in nameslist: 
    df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file/" + name + ".csv", index_col = 0)
    df = datacropper(df, 400, 800)
    df.to_csv("/path/to/file/" + 'cut-' + name + ".csv")
```